# here'ActiveRecord - Optional matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a Case model, which has multiple relations, how can I create a query that matches one or more relation.

Example: Case has Company which has a name. Case also has many Sessions which have a response. I want to create a query where I can search for one or more of those matching (Company name AND/OR Session response). If there's no company, but a Session response matches, it should return and visa versa.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
sql_cond = 'companies.id IS NOT NULL OR sessions.id IS NOT NULL')
Case.includes(:company, :sessions).references(:company, :session).where(sql_cond)
```

It will return the `Case` records having at least 1 `Company` OR `Session` record associated.